# why is it wrong : "aus/von jemandem etwas wegnehmen"?

Tags: preposition, dative

I was doing German grammatical exercises and came across this sentence:

**Er nimmt dem Kind den Ball weg.**

I know "wegnehmen" means "to take away"，but I thought it should be:

**Er nimmt *aus/von* dem Kind den Ball weg**

To my knowledge, Dative case alone has the meaning "to/towards sb/sth"，and since the man didn't throw the ball to the kid; instead, he took it away from the kind, so I thought there should be a preposition "aus/von" to make the sentence clear.

However this is obviously wrong, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: There _is_ nothing to figure out. It's simply _jemandem (dat) etwas (acc) wegnehmen_. No other prepositions required or, in fact, permitted. (I suppose it could be argued that there's movement towards the taker, if you really must.)

Comment: To extend on @Ingmars claim that no preposition is allowed: *etwas von etwas wegnehmen* is only possible in case you take something *from a collection* of items: "Ich habe eins von den Bonbons weggenommen" - Which obviously doesn't make sense with the kid and the ball.

Answer (score 2):

> To my knowledge, Dative case alone has the meaning "to/towards sb/sth"

You are thinking about this in too literal a way.

Dative case expresses that an action is conducted in such a way that the dative object is involved in it, although not directly the target of the action. In a way, it is *the action* that is "brought to" the dative object, no matter which direction the action literally describes. Add to that that the distinction can, at times, be blurry.

Answer (score 1):

For the easy part: 'aus' would mean you are taking it from the inside.

But you do not use 'aus/von' because 'dem Kind' is used as the object here. If you would use 'von dem Kind' 'den Ball' would be the object and 'dem Kind' an adverb.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the error of your analysis.

> Dative case alone has the meaning "to/towards sb/sth"，and since the man didn't throw the ball to the kid

This is false. You just have to *learn*  by heart *jemandem (D) etwas (A) wegnehmen*.